# Is the micro averaged precision/recall/f1 score for multiclass classification always the same?

Tags: multiclass-classification, model-evaluations

I was under the impression from [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-metrics-made-simple-part-ii-the-f1-score-ebe8b2c2ca1) that in the micro averaging case for multi-class classification, the precision and recall are the same. This is because the number of false negatives and false positives are equal. Each classification error will cause a false positive for `X` and a false negative for `Y`.

However, in both my own experiments and in some from [the transformers library](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/token-classification), the micro averages for precision and recall are different, even though it is multi-class classification. Here is an example table:

```
           precision    recall  f1-score   support

 LOCderiv     0.7619    0.6154    0.6809        52
  PERpart     0.8724    0.8997    0.8858      4057
  OTHpart     0.9360    0.9466    0.9413       711
  ORGpart     0.7015    0.6989    0.7002       269
  LOCpart     0.7668    0.8488    0.8057       496
      LOC     0.8745    0.9191    0.8963       235
 ORGderiv     0.7723    0.8571    0.8125        91
 OTHderiv     0.4800    0.6667    0.5581        18
      OTH     0.5789    0.6875    0.6286        16
 PERderiv     0.5385    0.3889    0.4516        18
      PER     0.5000    0.5000    0.5000         2
      ORG     0.0000    0.0000    0.0000         3

micro avg     0.8574    0.8862    0.8715      5968
macro avg     0.8575    0.8862    0.8713      5968
```

These examples seem to be calculating the precision/recall from [this function](https://github.com/chakki-works/seqeval/blob/445d99798f6969f606dbf5978d936d5a8b33bbd1/seqeval/metrics/sequence_labeling.py#L187). Why would the precision, recall, and F1 be different?

Comment: Update: the reason had to do with the fact that seqeval was comparing two sequences. The length of two sequences can differ, so it was not a standard multiclass classification problem with one prediction for every true value. E.g., the number of total predicted entities was _not necessarily equal_ to the total number of true entities...`p = tp / total predicted entities`, while `r = tp / total true entities`.